# Sequelize column "id" if relation "xxx" not found

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I try to insert some data to my postgres database. I've created the database via postgres sql shell, then created models in my backend. Now I want to run some create operations to add data to the database but if i run node index.js I get an SequelizeDatabaseError: column... not found.

But I don't understand why, because the column exists definitively and I can't find any mistakes in my models. Maybe some of you can find a mistakes... or what am I doing wrong? Thanks!!!

Here my tables:

[image]

[image]

moviesModel.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
   const movies = sequelize.define(
      'movies',
      {
         id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
         },
         title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
         },
         genres: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false,
         },
         number_in_stock: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
         },
         daily_rental_rate: {
            type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
         },
         created_date: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
         },
         update_date: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
         },
      },
      {
         tableName: 'movies',
         // Change columns name.
         updatedAt: 'update_date',
         createdAt: 'created_date',
      },
   );
   
   return movies;
};
```

genresModel.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
   const genres = sequelize.define(
      'genres',
      {
         id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
         },
         name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
         },
         created_date: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
         },
         update_date: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
         },
      },
      {
         tableName: 'genres',
         // Change columns name.
         updatedAt: 'update_date',
         createdAt: 'created_date',
      },
   );

   return genres;
};
```

tester.js

```
const db = require('../startup/db');
const genres = db.genres;
const movies = db.movies;

movies
   .create({
      id: 'b60fe518-bb6c-11ea-b3de-0242ac130005',
      title: 'Die Hard',
      genre: '128f35c6-bb6f-11ea-b3de-0242ac130004',
      number_in_stock: 2,
      daily_rental_rate: 3.5,
   })
   .then((newMovie) => {
      console.log(newCompany.get());
   })
   .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error', err);
   });

genres
   .create({
      id: '128f35c6-bb6f-11ea-b3de-0242ac130004',
      name: 'Action',
   })
   .then((newGenre) => {
      console.log(newGenre);
   })
   .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error', err);
   });
```

Here the error message:
[image]

Comment: Your model has `genres` while your sample data has `genre`.  I cannot tell your intention here.  Did you want `movies` and `genres` to have a many-to-many relationship, or is `genres` just a typo?

Comment: I want to have a one-to-many-relationship. So one movie should have one genre but one genre can have multiple movies. And genres was a typo, but I still get the error. Sequelize tells me that it can't find the column id of relation movies while running the insert

Comment: In your `moviesModel.js`, you define the column as `genres`.  It is `genre` in the `movies` table in PostgreSQL and in the data you are trying to insert from `tester.js`.  If fixing that does not work for you, can you please post the complete error message you are getting?

Comment: I have changed the column in moviesMode.js to genre (error message below in the picture)

Comment: The error message may be misleading.  Can you please try creating the `genres` entry before creating the `movies` entry? I ask that because the order you specify should fail when inserting the "Die Hard" entry.  Also, can you please delete your answer and put the screen shot in your original question?

Comment: Done. Even if I change the order of creating the entries I still get this error. I also tried to create only one entry.

Comment: If I add genres.removeAttribute('id') in my model the create query executes. But why?? And I don't see any entry in my database.

Comment: I am sorry that I missed it, but you have the FK relationship backwards. In table `movies`, `genre` should reference `genres(id)`.  And table `genres` should not have an FK defined to `movies`.